# vgcreate fails with 'already exists in filesystem' error

Tags: linux, lvm, disk-image

I have an installation test environment, where occasionally an issue is observed causing volume group creation to fail.

At the beginning of test, the disk contains four partitions.

```
# parted -l
Model: ATA Micron_5100_MTFD (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 480GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  525MB   524MB   fat16        EFI system partition  boot, esp
 2      525MB   1050MB  524MB                Linux filesystem
 3      1050MB  33.3GB  32.2GB  ext4         Linux LVM             lvm
 4      33.3GB  463GB   429GB                Linux LVM             lvm
```

The intention is to create a new partition `/dev/sda6` and volume group `VG_TEST`.
Since the volume group might have been created in earlier tests, a pre-cleanup is done first.

When the issue hits, the `vgremove` command output says that group does not exist, but the `vgcreate` command fails with error that it already exists.

```
# sgdisk --new=6:904849408:925820927 --change-name=6:TEST-FS /dev/sda
Warning: The kernel is still using the old partition table.
The new table will be used at the next reboot or after you
run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8)
The operation has completed successfully.

# sleep 5

# partprobe /dev/sda

# vgremove -f VG_TEST
  Volume group "VG_TEST" not found
  Cannot process volume group VG_TEST

# rm -rf /dev/VG_TEST

# pvcreate  -ffy /dev/sda6
  Physical volume "/dev/sda6" successfully created.

# vgcreate VG_TEST /dev/sda6
  /dev/VG_TEST: already exists in filesystem
  Run `vgcreate --help' for more information.
```

(The removal of `/dev/VG_TEST` was added based on suggestion in this [link](https://listman.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/2003-February/009721.html), but it did not help anyways.)

At the end of the test, output of below commands were collected.

Here, `lsblk` shows this group, but it is missing in `vgs` output.

```
# lsblk
NAME                                                           MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda                                                              8:0    0 447.1G  0 disk
├─sda1                                                           8:1    0   500M  0 part
├─sda2                                                           8:2    0   500M  0 part
├─sda3                                                           8:3    0    30G  0 part /var/lib/docker
├─sda4                                                           8:4    0   400G  0 part
│ ├─VG_System-..
│ ..
└─sda6                                                           8:6    0    10G  0 part
  └─VG_TEST-sysimg                                             252:23   0     9G  0 lvm
sr0                                                             11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
sr1                                                             11:1    1  1024M  0 rom


# vgs

  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize    VFree
  VG_System   1  23   0 wz--n- <400.00g 138.87g

# pvs
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree
  /dev/sda4  VG_System lvm2 a--  <400.00g 138.87g
  /dev/sda6            lvm2 ---    10.00g  10.00g
```

What could be causing this issue?
How to correctly cleanup the volume group?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue with removable media and duplicate volume group names. Deleting `/dev/VG_TEST` you mentioned was not enough, I had to remove all entries in `/dev/mapper/VG_TEST-*`, too:

```
dmsetup remove VG_TEST-LV1 VG_TEST-LV2 ...
```

where `LV1`, `LV2`, ... are all logical volume names in `VG_TEST`.